# Configure Chef to only report issues

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I'm trying to configure a automation testing system on Linux that reports any inconsistency such as incorrect file permissions, failed services, etc on a custom Linux OS. I can write my own script to do that, but I need a general solution that supports a wide variety of situations and systems.
So, I was wondering if I can configure Chef to only report problems and inconsistencies on Linux, but not fix them?

Comment: You may also write your own [`inspec`](http://inspec.io/) profile for this kind of 'audit'

Comment: Can it inspect all the components of an OS?

Comment: Try it out to a ee if it fits or not, but as far as I know, yes. And there's also CIS profiles on http://supermarket.chef.io for compliance baseline.

Comment: InSpec was exactly what I was looking for. Lightweight, easy to use framework. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Kind of. We have a system called "why run mode" which tries to do a dry-run check of what Chef would probably do if executed. Unfortunately because Chef code is, at heart, arbitrary executable Ruby code we can't be 100% certain. That said, I would try it out and see if the output is enough for your use.

Comment: Thank you. All I need is to prevent Chef to make changes and only reports  inconsistencies.